# How to return to a loop after button press

Tags: ios, loops, button

I am taking an online course and one of the problems has you build a simple number guessing game.  That was easy enough.  However, I want to modify it to limit the number of guesses.  That would entail a loop for the number of guesses allowed.

When I try this, the code goes to the button press action and never returns to the loop.  I have tried everything I know to get it to work, google searches have not helped, and the instructor has not answered my question posted 4 days ago!

So in short how does one get code to return to a loop after finishing the code for the button press?

In words here is what I want to do:

```
generate random number

for x = 1 to 6

    get user guess in text field

    press button to check if correct

    if correct

        do something

    else

        continue loop for another guess 

    x = x+1
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you want.

The user interface is an event-driven activity -- things happen as a result of the user typing in a textField or tapping a button.  The code to handle the UI is distributed among the response routines that handle the events and you have to figure out where you can do each part of what you want to do.  It can be maddening!

A general answer is that the code to handle events is distributed among multiple methods and you have to have some sort of shared state so that each event response can know what to do. Some code somewhere starts a round of the game and initialize the number of guesses.  Your textField delegate routines get the user guess and store it in an instance variable or property.  When the user taps a button, the button-response code can check the answer in that property and keep track of the number of guesses.

To be specific, here is some pseudocode that does what you proposed in your question:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *currentGuess;
@property (nonatomic) int numberOfGuesses;


- (void) startNewRound {
    ...
    // some code that gets ready for the user to guess
    generate random number
    // initialize the number of guesses where button code can get at it
    self.numberOfGuesses = 0;
    ...
}

// This method is called when the user finishes typing
// a guess in the text field as a result of the user pressing Return
// (or however you manage the data entry).  The parameter is whatever
// the user typed as a guess.
- (void) userEnteredAGuess:(NSString *)guess
    // put the guess where the button-event code can get at it
    self.currentGuess = guess;
}

// This is the method that gets run when the user taps the
// "Check the Guess" button
- (IBACTION) tapButton:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (the guess in self.currentGuess is correct...) {
        // Do whatever you do when the guess is correct
    } else {
        // Do whatever you do when the guess is wrong
    }
    self.numberOfGuesses += 1;
    if (self.numberOfGuesses > guessLimit) {
        // Exceeded guess limit
        // Do whatever should happen --
        // re-initialize the guesses, decrement score, ... whatever
        // maybe...
        [self startNewRound];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  As you suggested I created another event nextGuessButton.  My plan was to have it hidden until user the user taps the checkAnswerButton.  Then the number of guesses would be compared to the max.  If guesses were still left then hide itself and unhide the checkAnswer and allow another guess.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code compiles trying to hide the button.  But the button does not go away.  Both _firstButton.hidden=YES; and [_firstButton setHidden:YES]; compile but neither accomplishes the job.  Same code for a label works though.  Sorry to be a bother.

Comment: Perhaps my comments mislead you.  I think you would check the number of guesses in the code that runs when you tap the checkAnswerButton -- I don't think you need or want a nextGuessButton.  When I have problems with things not changing in the interface it is because I'm running on the main thread and the code to update the screen doesn't get a chance to run.